# Select tables rows matching where condition based on two columns

Tags: sql, where-clause

I have following Result Set:

```
FieldTypeID    Level
1               0
2               0
2               1
3               0
```

From this set I want to select following rows:

```
FieldTypeID    Level
1               0
2               1
3               0
```

In short what I want to do is a write a SQL where condition which will filter out the Records whose `FieldTypeID = 2` and whose `Level = 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select fieldtypeid,level 
from [table]
WHERE fieldtypeid <> 2 
OR level = 1
```

Comment: If it fixed your problem, feel free to accept as an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT FieldTypeID, Level FROM [table] WHERE FieldTypeID <> 2 OR Level <> 0
```

Comment: Wrong: selects just nothing (in the given example).

Comment: That will exclude records with fieldtypeid = 2 as well as records with level 0 in other words for the given example it wont return any record.

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from your_table
where not(FieldTypeID = 2 and Level = 0)
```